# String formatting remove everything after </table> tag

Tags: java, html, string, html-table

I have a string of HTML that contains a table.
However in some cases there are characters after the `</table>` tag.
I want to remove everything after the `</table>` tag from the string.
Any ideas on how I might do this in Java?

Comment: Please provide sample input and the required output.

Comment: Sample:
<table>
  <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>
Some characters I want to get rid of.

Comment: Is the string like this **`"...SOME_TEXT </table> SOME_UNWANTED_CHARS SOME_MORE_TEXT ... </table> SOME_MORE_UNWANTED_CHARS SOME_OTHER_TEXT ...... "`**  ? and does **`...UNWANTED_CHARS`** contain **`spaces/newlines`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `str` is this string, you could do the following:

```
str = str.replaceAll("</table>.*","</table>");
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for every case. Read my "review" to your answer. @Baxter Understand what it actually does by reading regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as @Andrew Logvinov suggests.

> `str.replaceAll("</table>.*","</table>");`

What this means, is: take the literal String `"</table>"` follewed by any character `.` repeated zero or more times `*` and replace it for the literal String `"</table>"`

Note that this method replaces all (so it takes the first match and delete the rest of the string), so if you have multiple tables, or nested tables this won't work any good. Learn to use regular expressions for a better solution. (Or just work with indexOf and whatever methods are in the String class)

Comment: Your note is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
String endTableTag = "</table>";
String html = "<table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>yadayadayada";
int index = html.lastIndexOf(endTableTag);
String cleanedup;
if (index>-1) {
    // Removes everything after the last table end tag
    cleanedup = html.substring(0, index + endTableTag.length());
} else {
    cleanedup = html;
}
System.out.println(cleanedup);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "testabc</table>anothertest</table>hahhah";
test = str.substring(0, (str.lastIndexOf("</table>")+"</table>".length()));
System.out.println(str.substring(0, (str.lastIndexOf("</table>")+"</table>".length())));
System.out.println(test);
```

or to test it...

```
test.replaceAll("</table>.*","</table>"); would be better! ;)
```

Is good, but if you have more that 1  you might get problems! ;) So its better to work with "lastIndexOf()" imho!